# How to mount an NTFS external hard drive for read/write access in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, kernel, ntfs-3g, sheevaplug

I'm a Ubuntu (Jaunty Jackalope on a Sheevaplug) user trying to mount an external hard drive formatted NTFS for read/write access. I was hoping to accomplish this through the use of ntfs-3g, but there's a problem when trying to install this driver. Any ideas how to get this hard drive mounted for read/write access and/or these drivers installed?

```
root@debian:~# apt-get install ntfs-3g

Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 21%

Reading package lists... Done


Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 77%

Building dependency tree       


Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... Done

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ntfs-3g
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/28.5kB of archives.
After this operation, 152kB of additional disk space will be used.


Selecting previously deselected package ntfs-3g.
(Reading database ... 25534 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ntfs-3g (from .../ntfs-3g_1%3a2009.2.1-0ubuntu2_armel.deb) ...
Processing triggers for hal ...
Regenerating hal fdi cache ...
 * Restarting Hardware abstraction layer hald       [80G Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 000280d0
pgd = d0ad0000
[000280d0] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#6]
Modules linked in:
CPU: 0    Not tainted  (2.6.22.18 #1)
PC is at strnlen+0x20/0x34
LR is at vsnprintf+0x314/0x5b4
PC : [<c0240228>]    lr : [<c02414f8>]    psr: a0000013
sp : d26b1dc0  IP : d26b1dd0  fp : d26b1dcc
r10: ffffffff  r9 : ffffffff  r8 : 00000000
r7 : ffffffff  r6 : da2fa054  r5 : 000280d0  r4 : d26b1e40
r3 : c00c8994  r2 : 000280d0  r1 : fffffffe  r0 : 000280d0
Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  Segment user
Control: 0005317f  Table: 10ad0000  DAC: 00000015
Process udevadm (pid: 2472, stack limit = 0xd26b0268)
Stack: (0xd26b1dc0 to 0xd26b2000)
1dc0: d26b1e1c d26b1dd0 c02414f8 c0240218 0000001b 00000002 00000000 00000fce 
1de0: d26b1e5c 25d05fab da2fa054 c00d321a d26b1e44 0000001c 00000054 d2849000 
1e00: da2fa000 dff048c8 00000000 c03fc7a4 d26b1e38 d26b1e20 c0241864 c02411f4 
1e20: dff04870 d26b1e40 da2fa000 d26b1eec d26b1e48 c026ef10 c024184c c00d3219 
1e40: 000280d0 000280d0 d2849000 00001000 d2849000 d284900e d284901d d2849032 
1e60: d284903e 00000044 000280d0 c03f1574 00000000 00000000 ffffff9c c03f1574 
1e80: dff03158 000080d0 c03f1570 dfd41040 00000000 00000000 d26b1eec d26b1ea8 
1ea0: c01472ec c0146724 000280d0 00000010 c0772f40 d26b0000 40020000 4001f000 
1ec0: 00100073 df1099a0 dff03158 dff04870 df1099a0 dff03158 dff04870 df1099c0 
1ee0: d26b1efc d26b1ef0 c026e810 c026ee28 d26b1f44 d26b1f00 c019ca14 c026e7fc 
1f00: d26b1f74 d26b1f10 c0153c60 d26b1f70 00001000 4001f000 00000000 db4d31c0 
1f20: 4001f000 d26b1f70 00001000 4001f000 d26b0000 00000000 d26b1f6c d26b1f48 
1f40: c01625e8 c019c964 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 db4d31c0 00001000 
1f60: d26b1fa4 d26b1f70 c01629fc c0162540 00000000 00000000 00000022 00000000 
1f80: ffffffff 2a025020 2a025020 000007ff 00000003 c0027628 00000000 d26b1fa8 
1fa0: c0027480 c01629c8 2a025020 2a025020 00000007 4001f000 00001000 00000000 
1fc0: 2a025020 2a025020 000007ff 00000003 bed66f9c 0000000a 40180000 bed66f9c 
1fe0: 40170000 bed66ef8 400aab04 400fe3fc 60000010 00000007 65757274 00000000 
Backtrace: 
[<c0240208>] (strnlen+0x0/0x34) from [<c02414f8>] (vsnprintf+0x314/0x5b4)
[<c02411e4>] (vsnprintf+0x0/0x5b4) from [<c0241864>] (sprintf+0x2c/0x34)
[<c0241838>] (sprintf+0x0/0x34) from [<c026ef10>] (show_uevent+0xf8/0x140)
 r3:000280d0 r2:000280d0 r1:c00d3219
[<c026ee18>] (show_uevent+0x0/0x140) from [<c026e810>] (dev_attr_show+0x24/0x28)
 r7:df1099c0 r6:dff04870 r5:dff03158 r4:df1099a0
[<c026e7ec>] (dev_attr_show+0x0/0x28) from [<c019ca14>] (sysfs_read_file+0xc0/0x130)
[<c019c954>] (sysfs_read_file+0x0/0x130) from [<c01625e8>] (vfs_read+0xb8/0x148)
[<c0162530>] (vfs_read+0x0/0x148) from [<c01629fc>] (sys_read+0x44/0x70)
 r7:00001000 r6:db4d31c0 r5:00000000 r4:00000000
[<c01629b8>] (sys_read+0x0/0x70) from [<c0027480>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
 r8:c0027628 r7:00000003 r6:000007ff r5:2a025020 r4:2a025020
Code: ea000000 e2800001 e2511001 3a000002 (e5d03000)
```

Comment: IIRC Ubuntu 9.04 still had no NTFS drivers to read/write, or at least it was on an experimental state. I suggest you upgrade your Ubuntu to 10.04 at least, or upgrade the kernel and the NTFS driver separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with m0skit0 to upgrade your Ubuntu (BUT I doubt you can upgrade the Ubuntu for your Sheevaplug. You can read some details over here: http://www.newit.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=2113.0)

Also, you might wish to take a look in the following link:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

To mount device that is formatted with NTFS

> sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external

Last but not least, the following link might help too:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Hope it help.